# Extract multiple types of text from a column in html

Tags: python, html, url, csv, extract

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to extract data from a html page. There is a certain column of the table which is a mixture of text and URLs. I'd like to extract all the information from that column, keeping the links intact to a csv file (which I'll later save as an Excel file). Please advise me. Here's my code to extract just the text.

```
trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    try:
        RS_id = str(tds[5].get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

A few cells of the column have multiple URLs and I'd like to keep them the same.

Answer (score 1):

How is the data in that column written? If there is a clear pattern for how the URL is separated by other text, then you can use the string.split('character') command.

Say the column of data you care about has all of the entries split apart by a ',' character, then you would say:

```
column_data=RS_id.split(',')
```

This would give you a list of everything listed in that column, splitting it up every time there is a comma character. Then you just index the list to get the URL you're after. If there is no particular order to index the list by, you may have to do something like:

```
URL_list=[]
for item in column_data:
    if 'http' in item: URL_list.append(item)
```

EDIT:
check out how beautifulsoup parses the table: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

There should be a .href attribute for the text, which is the URL the hyperlink links to.